# Calender not showing after clicking on icon but showing after clicking on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have used bootstrap's datepicker plugin. But, calender is not shown after i click on the icon. I have to click on input field to display the calender?

```
 <label for="dob" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date Of Birth</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group date">
              <input id="dob" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="2012-02-12" type="text" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autofocus>
          <div class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          </div>
     </div>
```

script:

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
```

After i added id to parent element:

```
<label for="dob" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date Of Birth</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                  <input id="dob" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="2012-02-12" type="text" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autofocus>
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
              </div>
         </div>
```

and script:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

It gives error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

This exact [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lro8kxjx/6/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Lro8kxjx) is not working either.

Comment: @rasmeister yes, but that displays error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.glyphicon-th').click(function() {
$(".datepicker").focus();
 });
```

Try this to focus datepicker

Comment: this worked. But isn't it supposed to display without adding this?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap dont have datepicker of its own. As per my guess you must be using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . 
If it is so, You must have all the dependencies for the calendar to work.